# Why is 'density' different for current?

Tags: current-measurement, semiconductors, dimensions

Considering an N-type semiconductor, when we talk about carrier density, it means number of electrons per unit volume. But, when we define current density(J), it is measured as total current per unit area.

Why?

Why not volume?

Comment: Because current is flow : it is observed at one slice through the conductor (which has area). It doesn't depend at all on the length of the conductor (area * length = volume).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From first principles, to compute the current density at a point in space you:

1. select a small box around the point
2. add up \$\rho \vec{v}\$ for all of the particles in the box where \$\rho\$ is the electric charge of the particle and \$\vec{v}\$ its velocity vector
3. divide the sum by the volume of the box

So by unit analysis you have current density is charge x velocity / volume which is charge x length / time / length^3 or charge / time / area.

So, there's the origin of the "per unit area" part of current density.

Answer (score 7):

Current is a one-dimensional quantity, while charge is a zero-dimensional one. It doesn't really make sense to talk about current per volume, for the same reason it doesn't really make sense to talk about, say, how many strands per length a stranded wire has--the current (and the strands of wire) are the same all along the length; not just the same number, but *the same*.

On the other hand, charge is a zero-dimensional quantity; a charge is located at a point, with finite extent in all three dimensions. So it makes sense to talk about how much charge there is per volume.

In more technical terms, you could say that if something is invariant with respect to a dimension, it's meaningless to consider its density along that dimension.

Comment: I wouldn't say current is a one-dimensional quantity. Current is defined relative to a surface and is simply the rate at which charge passes through that surface.

Comment: @ErikR I at least tend to visualize current as streamlines, which are called lines for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Current is the rate of charge passing a point on a circuit, \$ \frac {dQ}{dT} \$ and measured in amperes.

If the current is spread across the cross-section of the conductor so the current density is given in amperes/unit area. This is useful in contexts other than semiconductors. 20 A through a 1.5 mm<sup>2</sup> wire, for example, has a current density of \$ \frac I A = \frac {20} {1.5} = 13.3 \ \textrm {A/mm}^2 \$.

Comment: Shouldn't that be 20/1.5 = 13.3 A/mm²?

Comment: Of course, thanks, @Hearth. That's one of the big simplifications that metric cable sizes facilitates.  Fixed.